# GoJS how can I arrange the nodes in a palette and diagram top down

Tags: javascript, jquery, gojs

I have a palette and diagram side by side using the same template.

```
  var template = $(go.Node, "Horizontal",
  $(go.Shape,
    { width: 15, height: 15, fill: "white" },
    new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
  $(go.TextBlock,
    new go.Binding("text", "color"))
);
```

I would like to arrange the nodes top down then one it reaches the bottom, it would warp and start top down again next to the previous "column"

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? do I need to change he template or is there some setting to achieve this

Here is a fiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/v61bufs0/

My end goal is to a have a list of emails in the palette then drag them into the diagram for a include list

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this and will answer the question in detail for the benefits of other:

To accomplish what I was after I split my templates for the palette and diagram so each has their own.

On the diagram I did not want the nodes draggable so I set its template `movable: false` so the user cannot drag the node again.

Then when creating the diagram you can specify a layout. So using a GridLayout I did the following:

```
var  myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", 
{
   layout: $(go.GridLayout,
   {
                cellSize: new go.Size(200, 20),
                wrappingColumn: 1
    }),     
   "undoManager.isEnabled": true 
});
```

I specified a single column.

I also set the contentAlighment property to top left:

```
myDiagram.startTransaction("");
myDiagram.contentAlignment = go.Spot.TopLeft;
myDiagram.commitTransaction("");
```

Since I did not want the diagram nodes draggable I set the `myDiagram.allowDragOut= false;` as well so that a node cannot be dragged out of the diagram.  I found if I did not do this even though a node was not draggable if it was selected I could drag the selection

For the pallet its the same concept for the layout:

```
  var myPalette = $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",
    {
        layout: $(go.GridLayout,
        {
            cellSize: new go.Size(200, 20),
            wrappingColumn: 1
        })      
    });
```

And also for the contentAlighment property:

```
myPalette.startTransaction("");
myPalette.contentAlignment = go.Spot.TopLeft;
myPalette.commitTransaction("");
```

The end result can be viewed in this revised JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/v61bufs0/9/